# How to split this code into two files? DB

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I want to use connection to database from DB.php file (you can see bellow) instead one that is inside my index.php. I don't want use 2 db connections.

So, I already have connection to database, I just want remove it from index.php with DB.php, I want to use that method.

**DB.php**

```
private function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I want to use that connect instead of this one inside
**index.php**

```
    else if($_GET['action'] == 'news')
    {
        if(isset($_POST['tekst']))
        {
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "monkstud_db";
            try{
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "UPDATE pages SET body='".$_POST['tekst']."' WHERE id=1";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                //echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $conn = null;
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="tekst" id="tekst">

            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form><br><br>
        <?php
        $user = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT body FROM pages WHERE id= 1");

        if($user->count()){
            echo $user->first()->body;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You appear to already have one `DB::getInstance()`. Just use that one

Comment: @Rasclatt Its working! :D but do i need something else or just leave this one line? Because its working perfect with only this: `DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE pages SET body='".$_POST['tekst']."' WHERE id=1");`

Comment: You will probably want to investigate that `DB::instance()` to see if there is a `bind` feature. It's not safe to include the `$_POST` right into the sql

Comment: You need to look in the `class DB` for the binding. Look for `bindParam` or look for a bind array inside the `->execute(array())`

Comment: @Rasclatt This is what i have there: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8zcu89bs/)

Comment: Oh yeah there you go, the second params from the query, you put the value in an array there.

Comment: So something like `DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE pages SET body= :0 WHERE id=1", array($_POST['tekst']));`

Comment: @Rasclatt I did that and i get this: `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\classes\DB.php on line 36`

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that the `$x = 1;` on the loop, and I did `body= :0`. Should be `body = :1`.

Comment: @Rasclatt Same warning...here is the whole code of the DB.php if you want... https://jsfiddle.net/dLmja0x5/

Comment: Can you post up top what you have now as an edit?

Comment: Is this some library you downloaded off Github or something?

Comment: @Rasclatt https://jsfiddle.net/jz05tooc/

Comment: @Rasclatt Nah...that code is from codecourse tutorial on how to make login/register system using oop.

Comment: @Rasclatt I did it. I put `?` instead `:1` and its working...but i want to be sure is that it? Is it safe to use only that one line? `DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE pages SET body = ? WHERE id=1", array($_POST['tekst']));`

Comment: @Rasclatt Thank you so much! :D damn...its not that easy...i had to switch from old to this new system because of prepare...and now learning again everything lol...thank you anyway.